# Select Recyclerview Item

Tags: android

I am creating an app in which i am showing contact list in Recycler View and list is coming from server,i have already set data in Recycler View but now i want to select any five contact from Recycler View list and after selection want to set this selected item in another fragment.I have already created fragment but i don't know how to select item and set it another fragment?

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(this);
gestureDetector =
            new GestureDetectorCompat(mContext, new RecyclerViewDemoOnGestureListener());

public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId())
    {
       case  R.id.itemcontainer:
        int idx = recyclerView.getChildPosition(view);
        if (actionMode != null) {
            myToggleSelection(idx);
            return;
        }
    }
}
 private void myToggleSelection(int idx) {
    contactAdapter.toggleSelection(idx);
    String title = getString(R.string.selected_count, contactAdapter.getSelectedItemCount());
   // actionMode.setTitle(title);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
    gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e);
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateActionMode(android.view.ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareActionMode(android.view.ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onActionItemClicked(android.view.ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem menuItem) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyActionMode(android.view.ActionMode actionMode) {

}


private class RecyclerViewDemoOnGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        View view = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        onClick(view);
        return super.onSingleTapConfirmed(e);
    }

    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        View view = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (actionMode != null) {
            return;
        }
        // Start the CAB using the ActionMode.Callback defined above
      //  actionMode = startActionMode(getActivity());
        int idx = recyclerView.getChildPosition(view);
        myToggleSelection(idx);
        super.onLongPress(e);
    }
}
```